# How do you stop the "category path" being put in URL's generated by {path=}

Tags: categories, templates, ee3

ExpressionEngine 3.5.10.

I am outputting a specific list of categories (`category_group="1"`) from a channel of training courses (`channel="training"`). Followed by the list of courses assigned to that category. I have then used the Grid type field to store some details of when particular courses run, their price, etc. For example:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" channel="training" show_empty="no"}


    {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}"}

        <!-- Output name of course -->

        {training_booking_options}
            <!-- Output options for this course, e.g. price -->
            <a href="{path='contact-us'}">contact us</a>
        {/training_booking_options}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Wherever I use `{path=""}` it is outputting the category URL path in the URL. For example: `<a href="{path='contact-us'}">contact us</a>` gives URL's such as:

- http://dev.domain/contact-us/category/asia
- http://dev.domain/contact-us/category/health-and-safety
- http://dev.domain/contact-us/category/information-technology

I want the URL to be what I've put, i.e. http://dev.domain/contact-us regardless of the category it's within at the time the link is output.

Is this possible, or should I just abandon using `path=` and hardcode it like `<a href="/contact-us">contact us</a>`?

I don't want to use any of the "category name in URL" features for this particular section of the website. But there are other sections where I do want to use it. So I don't want a solution which disables it for the entire site!

Comment: I never use path, always use relative links, always.

Comment: I have to agree with that. I don't think `{path=}` does anything useful anyway. All it seems to do is prepend the base URL....to a URL string which you still have to define anyway! Doesn't seem very useful as obviously you can output the base URL with PHP anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do it I think will be to construct the URL from components. (as is clear from answer above) I'm not so clear on what your setup is, but something like this might work:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" channel="training" show_empty="no"}


    {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}"}

        <!-- Output name of course -->

        {training_booking_options}
            <!-- Output options for this course, e.g. price -->
            <a href="{path='SITE_INDEX'}/contact-us/{category_url_title}">contact us</a>
        {/training_booking_options}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortuantely this doesn't work. Did you try it? The URL's end up with the channel entry slug in them (as opposed to the category slug). So it's still not `/contact-us`, it's `/contact-us/channel-entry-url`. I don't think it's possible in EE so just going to hardcode a relative link.

Comment: ahah - I misunderstood your question :] - or rather what you were getting from the categories tag.  

The only way to do it I think will be to construct the URL from components.  (as is clear from answer above) I'm not so clear on what your setup is, but something like this might work:

`<a href="{path='SITE_INDEX'}/contact-us/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>`

HTH